# How to get and update user attributes AWS amplify angular 6

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

How would I change the attributes of the Cognito user after sign up into the application? What API should be used to fetch the details of the user like First Name, Last Name etc?
What API should be used to update the user details?

Answer (score 7):

To [fetch the details of the user](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#currentauthenticateduser), simply use `this.amplifyService.auth().currentAuthenticatedUser()` and retrieve the `user.attributes` fields.

```
/**
 * Get current authenticated user
 * @return - A promise resolves to curret authenticated CognitoUser if success
 */
currentAuthenticatedUser(): Promise<CognitoUser | any>;
```

To [update the attributes](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#updateuserattributes), use the `updateUserAttributes`method.

```
/**
 * Update an authenticated users' attributes
 * @param {CognitoUser} - The currently logged in user object
 * @return {Promise}
 **/
updateUserAttributes(user: CognitoUser | any, attributes: object): Promise<string>;
```

If you need to retrieve the `CognitoUser`, you can follow the [`Change password` example](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#change-password) of the documentation :

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(user => {
        return Auth.changePassword(user, 'oldPassword', 'newPassword');
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```