# Retrieving a Cognito user password age or create date

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have a requirement to force a password rotation on a schedule.  Is it possible with boto3 / botocore to retrieve the create date or password age for the latest password for a user in cognito?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [User Pool Attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html) to save the updated date that the user last created or updated their password. Then use a [Post Authentication trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-triggers.html) to determine if the value from the user attribute satisfies the parameters. If not, notify the user in the response that they need to change their password.

You can also use Amplify on the FrontEnd to obtain [currentAuthenticatedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653219/how-to-get-and-update-user-attributes-aws-amplify-angular-6) Attributes and do your processing on the FrontEnd, where if the last update to their password in the timestamp of the User Pool Attribute is more than 6 months, then notify them that they need to change their password and redirect them to a change password page.

You could do the same thing in your DB too for the user's data if you desire.